# Compatibility issue with Android pre lollipop versions

Tags: android, compatibility

I am writing some code for a Android app using fab icon, view pager, list view etc.

My app run smoothly on lollipop but when I run the app on Android api 12-16 it gives some issue that I am not able to understand and resolve.

Link:https://gist.github.com/sukhbir-singh/24fe0140a67730fd284c

Comment: The `android.widget.ImageButton` is not available; thus the XML fails to inflate.
First make sure it's not just a device-specific issue then assume it's an "api level change" thing ;)

Comment: Post code for `PersonListFragment.java` and it's xml file

Comment: @Msp I have updated the gist link, which include these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this line in `fragment_person_list.xml`,

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/fab_plus"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab_button"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_shape"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/fab_raise"   // here
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    />
```

Because, `StateListAnimator` is available only on API 21 and up. If you try to run this code on a lower version, app will crash.

What you can do is, remove that line from XML. And add it via code. Like this,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: I removed those line but still it doesn't work on pre lollipop

Comment: Yes, still same error occurs I even tried removing elevation but still doesn't works...